Can tag edits no longer allow you to submit closed posts for review in the reopen queue?
Currently, when editing a closed question, you can check “Submit for review” which I think places it into the reopen queue. An edit solely changing tags can do this as well. But, questions aren’t closed because of their tags, so changing what tags a question has shouldn’t allow you to nominate it for reopening as there is no way to, through just a tag edit, solve the reason(s) that the question was closed.
So, can tag edits no longer allow you to submit closed posts for review in the reopen queue?


…as there is no way to, through just a tag edit, solve the reason(s) that the question was closed.

Not true on some sites. On sites like RPG, Sci-fi & Fantasy, Movies & TV, Anime & Manga, Board & Card Games, and Arqade, it's often unclear what game/movie/etc. is being talked about without the proper tag, justifying closure under "Unclear what you're asking". (This happens often enough on RPG at least.) Adding the tag (usually only possible by OP, though sometimes it can be properly guessed by the experts) fixes the issue.

So possibly it could be disabled on a few sites then but enabled for most of the network where that is not the case

Tags aren't enough. The same question might be asked of several different things, but adding all the tags will only make it worse. That detail should be in the question body.

In addition to adding tags, sometimes removing tags can clarify a question, if the tags contradict the question body.

This seems to be a theoretical issue that has little meaning in practice. I hope that the person editing the closed question comes to the conclusion that the 'Submit for review' option shouldn't be checked without good reason.
And even if a few slip through, the review queue will promptly reject the reopen requests. I don't see this as an issue that needs to be fixed.
